# Events into all properties of a control vs events into an event handler, in Xpages

Tags: events, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am trying to understand the difference between events (onclick, onfocus, etc...) that exist in a control's "all properties" tab and the same events in the event handler of a control.

When trying to add client or server code in an "all properties onclick" it is executed on page load before i even try to do anything... (same for onfocus, onkeydown etc, they are all executed on page load immediately).

Any explanation? (or link with expanation)
(of course i always work with event handlers and i am ok with it but...i am just wondering.)

Comment: What does it show in the XML markup on the source tab for each? Sounds like it's computing a property rather than adding an eventHandler. If you can paste the XML, that will help us explain for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, events you have added into the component properties are the native events of the HTML component. You can only run client-side javascript here.

```
<input type="text" onchange="doStuff()" class="xspInputFieldEditBox" name="view:_id1:inputText1" id="view:_id1:inputText1">
```

Events added into an `eventHandler` are binded events. XPages has an eventHandler renderer which creates a javascript function and attach that into the component via `XSP.attachEvent` method on load.

Event handler also provides multiple CSJS events in an order. Therefore you might stop the rest of the code simply by returning false. For instance:

```
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onchange"
    submit="false">
    <xp:this.script>
        <xp:scriptGroup>
            <xp:executeClientScript
                script="if(! confirm('Confirm the next action?')) return false;"></xp:executeClientScript>
            <xp:executeClientScript
                script="doStuff();"></xp:executeClientScript>
        </xp:scriptGroup>
    </xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

This script group will stop if the user clicks cancel on the confirm dialog.

This event mechanism has additional functionality. It can create a GET/POST ajax request back to the server (serverside code through a managed bean or SSJS) and partial/full refresh on the page in addition to the control over validation, partial execution, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. While i was suspecting that it is indeed the native events of html, i see that server side code is also executed in there, but on page load and not when the event occurs.

Comment: If you refer server-side binding, that's a different story. In the above code, `script="doStuff('#{javascript:someSSJSstuff()}')` would be an example. You render a SSJS code and XSP is putting the result into the XML markup. That's not an event, as Paul said above.